# Send ArrayList<String> with Retrofit to server

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to retrofit, i am trying to send arraylist<> of type string to server,

I have seen several solution on stack-overflow.

I am having problem on the method side. I don't know how can I send the array-list inside the method.

I have tried 2 different ways

**Method1:**

**Here is my Interface:**

```
@Multipart
@PUT("profile")
Call<ProfileSetupResponse3> vendorProfile3(
        @Header("access-token") String token,
        @Part("name") RequestBody name,
        @Part("step") RequestBody step,
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part("highlights") RequestBody highlights,
        @Part("minQuantity") RequestBody minQuantity,
        @Part("available") RequestBody available,
        @Part("warrantyDetail") RequestBody warrantyDetail,
        @Part("warrentyPeriod") RequestBody warrentyPeriod,
        **@Query("categories[]") ArrayList<RequestBody> categories**
    
);


ArrayList<RequestBody> cat = new ArrayList<>();
            cat.add(createFromString("Paintsas"));
Call<ProfileSetupResponse3> call = RetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getApi()
                    .vendorProfile3(....,cat)
```

**Method2:**

```
@Query("categories[]") ArrayList<String> categories

ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
categories.add("APskaoj");
            categories.add("APskaoj");
            categories.add("APskaoj");
Call<ProfileSetupResponse3> call = RetrofitClient
                    .getInstance()
                    .getApi()
                    .vendorProfile3(....,categories)
```

Still I am not able to send my arraylist to server.

Some help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I cannot comment...

The Query parameter is appended to the URL for example:

```
 @GET("/friends")

 Call<ResponseBody> friends(@Query("page") int page);
 
 Calling with foo.friends(1) yields /friends?page=1.
```

This is from the documentation of Retrofit2: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

Without seeing the API specification. I would say change the @Query to be @Body